# Right Click Drag and Drop Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

so I'm trying to perform a right click drag and drop using Selenium webdriver, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to do this?

I have tried using ActionChains to do it, but they dont seem to run.

Comment: Action chains should work.  Can you post what you tried with action chains?

Comment: Hope when you say action you mean dragAndDrop method under action? If not you can use this to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

For right click with mouse you can use

```
WebElement elementToRightClick = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfba")); 
Actions clicker = new Actions(driver); 
clicker.contextClick(elementToRightClick).perform();
```

For drag&drop, you can use

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(source Element).moveToElement(target Element).release(target Element).build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

(or)

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.dragAndDrop(source Element, target Element).build();
dragAndDrop.perform();
```